# Pandas Filtering

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that I am getting some counts on, like so:

```
t = df['NAME'].value_counts()[:10]
```

I would then like to reduce the original data set (df) to only include items that match t. Something like:

```
temp = df[t]
```

or

```
temp = df[df['NAME'] in t]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df[df.name.isin(t.index)]
```

Comment: If you don't mind, can you provide a bit of info on the .index attribute? I looked through the manual, but was only able to find the .str.index method, which isn't this.

Comment: @browskie  The output of value_counts is a series (which you called `t`).  `t.index` is just the index of that series.